# OR inside Joins in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to know what's wrong with putting `OR` inside the `JOIN`, because it seems not to be responding to the 2 conditions: `(k0.keyword = 'Nombre' AND k0.value LIKE 'Cliente3') OR (k0.keyword = 'Nombre' AND k0.value = 'Cliente4'))`. Its always returning the full table content, and should only return 5 sets. I'm currently using multiple joins, I just was testing something and came up with this and would like to understand this behaviour.

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, d.created, d.updated 
FROM documents d 
     INNER JOIN permissions p 
     ON (d.wfid = p.wfId AND d.docid = p.docId AND p.userid = 1) 
     INNER JOIN keywords k0 
     ON (k0.document_id = d.id AND (k0.keyword = 'Nombre' AND k0.value LIKE 'Cliente3') 
         OR (k0.keyword = 'Nombre' AND k0.value = 'Cliente4')) 
ORDER BY k0.value DESC, d.id DESC LIMIT 0, 12;

+------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | name                        | created             | updated             |
+------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 5355 | Documento - Digitalización  | 2014-03-31 12:57:51 | 2014-03-31 12:57:51 |
| 5354 | Documento - Digitalización  | 2014-03-28 11:14:11 | 2014-03-28 11:14:11 |
| 5270 | DOC2                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 13:41:57 |
| 5269 | DOC2                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:39:51 |
| 5268 | DOC2                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:39:25 |
| 5267 | DOC1                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:39:10 |
| 5266 | DOC1                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-03-06 01:35:16 |
| 5265 | DOC1                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:38:37 |
| 5264 | DOC1                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:38:25 |
| 5263 | DOC1                        | 2014-04-07 11:23:00 | 2014-03-20 09:54:30 |
| 5269 | DOC2                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:39:51 |
| 5268 | DOC2                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:39:25 |
+------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from keywords where keyword = 'Nombre';
+-------+-------------+---------+----------+
| id    | document_id | keyword | value    |
+-------+-------------+---------+----------+
| 15888 |        5263 | Nombre  | Cliente1 |
| 15889 |        5264 | Nombre  | Cliente1 |
| 15890 |        5265 | Nombre  | Cliente1 |
| 15891 |        5266 | Nombre  | Cliente2 |
| 15892 |        5267 | Nombre  | Cliente3 |
| 15893 |        5268 | Nombre  | Cliente3 |
| 15894 |        5269 | Nombre  | Cliente3 |
| 15895 |        5270 | Nombre  | Cliente4 |
+-------+-------------+---------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Something to do with your parenthesis, maybe?  Try this: `ON k0.document_id = d.id AND ((k0.keyword = 'Nombre' AND k0.value LIKE 'Cliente3') OR (k0.keyword = 'Nombre' AND k0.value = 'Cliente4'))`.  Or since they both share `k0.keyword = 'Nombre'`, try: `ON k0.document_id = d.id AND k0.keyword = 'Nombre' AND k0.value IN ('Cliente3', 'Cliente4')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `OR` criteria is messed up slightly.  Try moving your parentheses:

```
k0.document_id = d.id AND 
((k0.keyword = 'Nombre' AND k0.value LIKE 'Cliente3') OR 
     (k0.keyword = 'Nombre' AND k0.value = 'Cliente4'))
```

This should keep your join in tact.

Comment: Thanks. Should be better to do this way or with multiple joins?

Comment: @Jorge -- I don't think you want to use multiple joins in this particular case, so this works well.  With that said, RocketHazmat's solution is a cleaner way to write the same thing.  I just wanted to point out your missing parentheses.  Glad we could help!

Answer (score 2):

Since both of your clauses check `k0.keyword = 'Nombre'`, why not just simply use `IN` for `k0.value`?

```
INNER JOIN keywords k0 ON k0.document_id = d.id
    AND k0.keyword = 'Nombre'
    AND k0.value IN ('Cliente3', 'Cliente4')
```

Comment: +1 -- I prefer this solution.  I just wanted to point out the error with the existing query.

Comment: Yes, it is good with the example I gave, but I omitted to say that `keyword` can be anything, not just `Nombre`, and can be in conjuntion with other keywords, in  more refined search